# How do I check if a user has a specific role? | discord.js v13

Tags: discord.js

How do I check if a user has a specific role? However, not by mentioning the user but through their ID. so, obviously this wouldn't work:

```
message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'ROLE')
```

neither does `client.users.cache.get('ID');` have a property allowing me to access their roles. neither does `client.users.fetch`. So how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.users.fetch()` and `client.users.cache.get()` both return `User`s which don't have roles. You need to get a `GuildMember` from a guild

```js
let member = guild.members.cache.get("id")
let hasRole = member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'ROLE')
```